# Count conditionally formatted cells in each row until last row

Tags: excel, vba

I found this working solution to count conditionally formatted cells:

```vb
Sub CountColorCellsAQ3()

'Variable declaration
Dim rng As Range
Dim lColorCounter As Long
Dim rngCell As Range
'Set the range of cells to count
Set rng = Sheet2.Range("B2:Y2")
'loop throught each cell in the range
For Each rngCell In rng
    'Checking Red color
    If Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180) Then
        lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
    End If
Next
'Display the total number of red cells in cell listed below
ActiveSheet.Range("AB2") = lColorCounter

End Sub
```

It works only for one row and writes a result to one predefined cell.

How can I count formatted cells (range will be the same, but in different row) in every row till last row and put result near every row in dedicated Result column.

Every row is a different person, so I need to count colored cells for each person individually.

Comment: What does "count formatted cells" mean? Doesn't it count the cells having `Interior.Color = RGB(198, 224, 180)`, independent of conditional formatted or not? Should be `RGB(198, 224, 180)` color the one used to be counted in all rows?

Comment: Yes, it should be the one to be counted and there will be only this one color. With this color we are highlighting wrong answers. So counted highlighted cells indicates for us how many mistakes each person made.

Comment: Then, please try the answer I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: But you must know that in case of conditional formatted cells, the conditional interior color is returned by the code. If the checking is done by these conditional formatted cells, **it is OK**. Otherwise, if the checking is done manually, you should use `Interior.Color` instead of `DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It will count each row interior color having a specific value and return the count on Z:Z column

```
Sub CountColorCellsAQ3()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, lColorCounter As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long, checkColor As Long
    
    checkColor = RGB(198, 224, 180)
    Set sh = Sheet2
    lastRow = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    
    'Set the range of cells to count
    Set rng = sh.Range("B2:Y" & lastRow)
    lastCol = rng.rows(1).cells.count 'last column
    'loop throught each cell in the range
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        'counting interior specific colored cells, for each row:        
        For j = 1 To lastCol
            If sh.cells(i, j).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = checkColor Then
                lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
            End If
        Next j
         sh.cells(i + 1, "Z").Value = lColorCounter 'place the count in Z:Z column
                                                    'i + 1 because the range starts from the second row ("B2")...
        lColorCounter = 0                           'reinitialize the variable
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It's awesome! Last question, where to change to skip checking first row, because it's header row :)

Comment: @Daniel Is the header on the second row? If yes, you should build the range starting from "B3", but using `sh.cells(i + 2, ...` when returning the count.. Or let the range as it is but start counting from 2. `For i = 2 To lastRow`...

Comment: i've changed   For i = 2 To lastRow    and removed    + 1   from    sh.cells(i + 1,